# two jqgrid no data loaded

Tags: jqgrid

When I duplicate a working grid with a different id, data are not loaded in both grid.
Both grids are shown and they both query the same url. Json data is sent from php but data is not loaded into grid.

If i comment any of the grids, the other one loads data properly.

Any help greatly appreciated. I'm using jqgrid 4.4.1

Here is my code

```
<div class="row-fluid">
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function LoadgridInput () {
    jQuery('#gridInput').jqGrid({
    height:100,
    hoverrows:false,
    viewrecords:true,
    caption:"&nbsp;",cellEdit: true,rowNum:10000,
    scroll:1,
    rowList:[30,100,500],
    datatype:"json",
    url:"grid.php?sec=Agility&fn=gcSandFInput_V1",
    cellurl:"grid.php?sec=Agility&fn=gcSandFInput_V1",
    editurl:"grid.php?sec=Agility&fn=gcSandFInput_V1",
    sortname:"default",
    autowidth:true,
    shrinkToFit:true,
    gridview:false,
    pager:"#gridInputPager",
    postData:{oper:"grid"},
    jsonReader:{repeatitems:false,root: "rows",page: "page",total: "total",records: "records",repeatitems: true,cell: "cell",id: "id",userdata: "userdata"},
    colModel:[
    {name:" ",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60},{name:"04-2012",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"05-2012",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"06-2012",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"07-2012",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"08-2012",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"09-2012",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"10-2012",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"11-2012",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"12-2012",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"01-2013",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"02-2013",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"03-2013",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"04-2013",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"05-2013",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"06-2013",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"07-2013",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"08-2013",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"09-2013",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"10-2013",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 }]})

  jQuery('#gridInput').jqGrid('navGrid','#gridInputPager',{refresh:true,edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:true,view:false,"excel":true,"pdf":false,"csv":false,"columns":false},{"drag":true,"resize":true,"closeOnEscape":true,"dataheight":150,"errorTextFormat":function(r){ return r.responseText;}},{"drag":true,"resize":true,"closeOnEscape":true,"dataheight":150,"errorTextFormat":function(r){ return r.responseText;}},{"errorTextFormat":function(r){ return r.responseText;}},  {"drag":true,"resize":true,"closeOnEscape":true,"dataheight":150,"closeAfterSearch":true,"multipleSearch":false},{"drag":true,"resize":true,"closeOnEscape":true,"dataheight":150},{"drag":true,"resize":true,"closeOnEscape":true,"dataheight":150});

    };
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> runOnLoad(LoadgridInput); </script>
<div id="gridInputWrapper">
 <table id="gridInput"></table> <div id="gridInputPager"></div>
 <div class="gridInputFooter"></div>
</div>
</div>



<div class="row-fluid">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function LoadgridList () {
    jQuery('#gridList').jqGrid({
    height:100,
    hoverrows:false,
    viewrecords:true,
    caption:"&nbsp;",cellEdit: true,rowNum:10000,
    scroll:1,
    rowList:[30,100,500],
    datatype:"json",
    url:"grid.php?sec=Agility&fn=gcSandFInput_V1",
    cellurl:"grid.php?sec=Agility&fn=gcSandFInput_V1",
    editurl:"grid.php?sec=Agility&fn=gcSandFInput_V1",
    sortname:"default",
    autowidth:true,
    shrinkToFit:true,
    gridview:false,
    pager:"#gridListPager",
    postData:{oper:"grid"},
    jsonReader:{repeatitems:false,root: "rows",page: "page",total: "total",records: "records",repeatitems: true,cell: "cell",id: "id",userdata: "userdata"},
    colModel:[
    {name:" ",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60},{name:"04-2012",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"05-2012",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"06-2012",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"07-2012",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"08-2012",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"09-2012",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"10-2012",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"11-2012",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"12-2012",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"01-2013",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"02-2013",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"03-2013",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"04-2013",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"05-2013",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"06-2013",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"07-2013",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"08-2013",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"09-2013",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 },{name:"10-2013",index:"nope",align:"left",search:true,editable:false,width:60 }]})
    jQuery('#gridList').jqGrid('navGrid','#gridListPager',{refresh:true,edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:true,view:false,"excel":true,"pdf":false,"csv":false,"columns":false},{"drag":true,"resize":true,"closeOnEscape":true,"dataheight":150,"errorTextFormat":function(r){ return r.responseText;}},{"drag":true,"resize":true,"closeOnEscape":true,"dataheight":150,"errorTextFormat":function(r){ return r.responseText;}},{"errorTextFormat":function(r){ return r.responseText;}},  {"drag":true,"resize":true,"closeOnEscape":true,"dataheight":150,"closeAfterSearch":true,"multipleSearch":false},{"drag":true,"resize":true,"closeOnEscape":true,"dataheight":150},{"drag":true,"resize":true,"closeOnEscape":true,"dataheight":150});

    };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">runOnLoad(LoadgridList);</script>
<div id="gridListWrapper">
    <table id="gridList"></table> <div id="gridListPager"></div>
    <div class="gridListFooter"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you see any error messages in your console?

Comment: No error in firebug console. the two grids show "loading" for 2 seconds, then it disappears with a small delay between the two grids. Firebug shows the two calls the web server and the correct json array returned. But the grids stay empty.

Comment: Making some progress. The json is actually NOT good. It contains Data for both grids. So there are two calls but each of those two calls send back the data for the two grids. humm..?

Comment: Solved. It was my php that didn't make the difference between the two grids and sent both results for each call. I changed oper:"grid" to oper:"gridName" gridName being different for each grid so php could decide which grid to reply to.